# How to avoid from my user to download all of the project's js and css external files at initial load, and instead, load them on demand?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

This is my index.html - as you can it has lots of external css and js files.
I wonder if there is any way to fix this.

See the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="main" ng-cloak>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>

    <!--favicon icon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">

    <!--common style-->
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.rtl.css" ng-if="$root.locale=='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" ng-if="$root.locale!='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/lobicard/css/lobicard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/wesather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--toastr-->
    <link href="assets/vendor/toastr-master/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--select2-->
    <link href="assets/vendor/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' />

    <!--custom css-->
    <link href="assets/css/main.rtl.css" ng-if="$root.locale=='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" ng-if="$root.locale!='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.rtl.css" ng-if="$root.locale=='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" ng-if="$root.locale!='he-IL'" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom-both.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body ng-show="initSrc" class="app header-fixed left-sidebar-fixed right-sidebar-fixed right-sidebar-overlay right-sidebar-hidden">

    <app></app>

    <!-- assets scripts -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular-route.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.7.2/angular-sanitize.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-animate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src="assets/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-ui-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch-improved.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="assets/vendor/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/lobicard/js/lobicard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/date-picker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!--toastr-->
    <script src="assets/vendor/toastr-master/toastr.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- app scripts -->
    <script src="app/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/run.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- app services -->
    <script src="app/services/helpers/modules-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/helpers/defaults-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/helpers/query-string-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/helpers/object-manipulation-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/helpers/array-manipulation-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/helpers/auto-redirect-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/init-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/http-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/filter-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/cast-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/socket-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/local-storage-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/authentication-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/parse-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/translation-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/toast-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="app/services/confirmation-modal-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- shared screens -->
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users/users.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users/components/list-users/list-users.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users/components/create-user-modal/create-user-modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users/components/attach-user-to-department-modal/attach-user-to-department-modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users-detail/users-detail.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/users-detail/components/edit-user/edit-user.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/departments/departments.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/departments/components/list-departments/list-departments.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/departments/components/create-department-modal/create-department-modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/departments-detail/departments-detail.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/cardboards/departments-detail/components/edit-department/edit-department.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/settings/permissions/permissions.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/shared/settings/permissions/components/permissions-table/permissions-table.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- root screens -->
    <script src="screens/root/overview/overview.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/root/cardboards/suppliers/suppliers.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/root/cardboards/suppliers/components/create-suppliers-modal/create-suppliers-modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/root/cardboards/suppliers/components/edit-supplier/edit-supplier.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/root/cardboards/suppliers/components/list-suppliers/list-suppliers.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- suppliers screens -->
    <script src="screens/suppliers/overview/overview.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/suppliers/account/general-details/general-details.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/suppliers/account/billing/billing.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/suppliers/account/payment-methods/payment-methods.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- auth screens -->
    <script src="screens/auth/login/login.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/auth/login/components/request-sms/request-sms.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="screens/auth/login/components/reset-password/reset-password.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- shared components -->
    <script src="shared/forms/services/selector-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/forms/datepicker/datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/forms/smart-select/smart-select.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/forms/text-input/text-input.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/forms/autocomplete/autocomplete.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/forms/birthday-input/birthday-input.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/filters/pagination/pagination.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/filters/search-filter/search-filter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/filters/status-filter/status-filter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/filters/sort-filter/sort-filter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/filters/date-filter/date-filter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/general-errors/general-errors.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/confirmation-modal/confirmation-modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/status-badge/status-badge.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/page-title/page-title.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/page-title/services/breadcrumb-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/list-header/list-header.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/loading-spinner/loading-spinner.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/alert-bar/alert-bar.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/no-content-placeholder/no-content-placeholder.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="shared/dropdown/dropdown.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- structure scripts -->
    <script src="structure/header/header.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/header/components/save-button/save-button.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/header/components/profile-menu/profile-menu.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/footer/footer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/sidebar/sidebar.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/sidebar/services/path-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/sidebar/services/menu-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/sidebar/services/root-menu-exporter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/sidebar/services/supplier-menu-exporter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="structure/aside/aside.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- analytical scripts -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I have tried to wrap the project using Webpack and build one bundle file for those JS external codes.
However I don't find this way of working to be so efficient - I still let my users to download 
the whole project's components, controllers and services at initial load - which is for sure not the 
right way to make it.

In old web development you would include only the required structural external js and css and 
the specific files that are required for the same page.

Since this is a SPA app, how should it be done?

And I have some more tiny question about AngularJS services injections.

In order to use a service in a controller I have to first inject it.

But I anyway have to load it's js file in the index.html and request it's data from a remote server - even when I don't injects and use it in any controller.

So if I anyway processing the service, why should I inject it or maybe, why the injection doesn't includes the async request of the file's code?

Comment: Take a look at https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Comment: `ng-if` in header elements definitely will not work as the AngularJS framework waits for [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) before compiling the `ng-if` directive.  Read [MDN DOMContentLoaded - Optimizing parsing speed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded#Optimize_parsing_speed).

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried this but it didn't work. Maybe could you please provide with an example based on what I have provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the user to download the code. One thing you can do is uglify & combine all the JS files in one file & css files in one file. So, if someone download your code they can't understand the logic written in the source.